# Is it possible to move this Windows Forms DevExpress design "helper"?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I tried moving or hiding this thing without luck.

Is is possible to do it?

Thanks!

[image: Image of the "design helper"]

Comment: If you are looking to do this as a one-off action,you can click on the little tiny right-arrow at the top right of the grid and untick 'Show level Designer'.

Comment: @sgmoore I forgot to tell you thanks for answering!

Comment: Accept his answer then, please.

Comment: I dont think I can @MarkoJuvančič